# scrapy why jsessionid is appened to url when call extract?

Tags: scrapy

why jsessionid is appened to url when call extract?

```
response.css('.pan-con dl > dt > h2 > a::attr(href)').extract()
```

['/xf/jintianxincheng2qi;jsessionid=TBg8OmdAj97Als+x9wVX2UOu.undefined', '/xf/lufuzangyuexiaoqu;jsessionid=TBg8OmdAj97Als+x9wVX2UOu.undefined', '/xf/dongchengzhixingguandi4qi;jsessionid=TBg8OmdAj97Als+x9wVX2UOu.undefined', '/xf/changjianxingyuecheng2qi;jsessionid=TBg8OmdAj97Als+x9wVX2UOu.undefined', '/xf/huaxiyishucunxidou;jsessionid=TBg8OmdAj97Als+x9wVX2UOu.undefined', '/xf/wanjingfeng2qi;jsessionid=TBg8OmdAj97Als+x9wVX2UOu.undefined', '/xf/gongyuanshijia;jse

Comment: Are you trying to catch any cookies in your code?

Comment: Because `jsessionid` is a part of `href` attribute. Check page source in your browser (`Ctrl+U`).

Comment: @gangabass, checked, it is not.

Comment: @MuratDemir nope

Comment: Could you show your target website URL?